# Syntax Error when writing to my Access database

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, oledb

I got this code inside a method:

```
string tableName = "messages_user-test";
                OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\janke\\source\\repos\\Unichat\\Unichat\\bin\\Debug\\history.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;");
                conn.Open();
                OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand();
                comm.Connection = conn;
                string writestring = "insert into " + tableName + " ([from], [to], [datetime], [message]) values (@from, @to, @datetime, @message);";
                Console.WriteLine(writestring);
                comm.CommandText = writestring;
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", from);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", to);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datetime", date);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@message", text);
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                comm.Dispose();
                conn.Close();
```

When I execute the program I get this error at `comm.ExecuteNonQuery();`

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: "Syntaxerror in INSERT INTO statement."
```

I am pretty new to OleDB and I have already read hundreds of threads about this error but nothing worked for me.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I swear I recall not having named parameter placeholders with Access and having to use `?` as placeholders in the query string. I could be wrong as it has been about 10 years since I've touched access.

Comment: I have already tried that, but it didnt work.

Comment: a) Use `?` as discussed. b) Change `messages_user-test` to `[messages_user-test]`. Does that work?

Comment: Yes that worked for me. Thanks alot! This has been bugging me for days!

Answer (score 0):

- Using square bracket for table name and field name
- Maybe the date (from, to, date) value that causing the error
- Don't forget to add try..catch
- Check the profiler for more detail

  ```
   using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\janke\\source\\repos\\Unichat\\Unichat\\bin\\Debug\\history.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"))
       {
           string strFeedback = "";

           string tableName = "messages_user-test";
           string writestring = string.Format("INSERT INTO [{0}] ([from], [to], [datetime], [message]) VALUES (@from, @to, @datetime, @message);", tableName);

           OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand(writestring);                
           comm.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@from", from.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")));
           comm.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@to", to.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")));
           comm.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@date", date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")));
           comm.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@message", text));
           try
           {
               strFeedback = comm.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString() + " record has been added successfully!";
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {

               strFeedback = "ERROR: " + err.Message;
           }           
       }
  ```